# Determining the form of elements in quotient ring of multivarible polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to find the elements in the quotient ring 
${F_2}\left[ {x,y} \right]/\left( {xy + 1} \right)$. I think that the elements of this ring are of the form ${a_0} + {a_1}{x^n} +{a_2} {y^m}$, ${a_i} \in {F_2}$ since the leading term 
$xy$ doesn't divide both ${x^n}$ and ${y^m}$. Here, $n$ and $m$ are nonnegative integers.

I don't know whether I'm right or not. Also, can we determine the form of elements for general case ${F_2}\left[ {x,y} \right]/
\left( {f\left( {x,y} \right)} \right)$, where 
${f\left( {x,y} \right)}$ is a polynomial with the leading term 
${x^n}{y^m}$.

I'll be pleasure if one gives an answer.

Comment: Yes. Whenever $x$ appears next to $y$, it can be canceled to $1$ (since the characteristic is $2$, $1=-1$). In particular, $x$ is a unit in the quaotient ring. If you think about it, this ring is just the Laurent polynomials $F_2[x,x^{-1}]$.

Comment: Thank you veru much rschwieb@.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the remainder must be in the form $${a_0} + {a_1}f\left( x \right) + {a_2}g\left( y \right).$$

Comment: I think you are right, sadecesad.

Comment: What about you for general case?, sadecesad

Comment: @egrtomath Can you rephrase the question in your last comment?